# C++. Optimize a programm that uses a lot of constant strings

Tags: c++, string

In my program I execute queries on a database. Most of the time these queries are fixed (i.e. `select * from table 1`) and are called by functions like this:

```
Table getTable1() {
return execQuery("select * from table1;");
}
```

Is it good to insert the constant queries inside the functions as I wrote here? Or is it better to create constant strings that contain these queries?

```
const string queryTable1 = "select * from table1;";
Table getTable1() {
return execQuery(queryTable1);
}
```

Comment: Of course to put them in constants is better if you put them all in one place, easier to find and fix). Even better should be to avoid hard coded SQL commands in your code...

Comment: Why would you create separate `const string`s?

Comment: What is the signature of `execQuery`? Does it take `const std::string&`?

Comment: @Adriano That's a great assertion (I mean the first part. of course avoiding hard-coded SQL would be good.)

Comment: @H2CO3 well it should be read as: "if you move that queries in constants and your group them together then IMO it's better. At least, if you can't avoid hard coded SQL, you'll have them in one place only and this will help you in case of changes".

Comment: Since this is a SQL operation, execQuery would take much more time than the string optimization part. It's just pointless to do such a premature optimization.

Comment: @CharlesBailey yes, it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably create a function with a parameter:

```
Table getTable(const std::string& tableName) { 
  return execQuery("select * from " + tableName + ";"); 
}
```

Comment: Does `::operator+` have a `const char *, const std::string &` overload? IIRC it hasn't, so you have to either add a functional-style cast to `std::string` around the first string literal, or use a C++11 suffix to make it an `std::string` literal, like this: `"select * from"s`.

Comment: Plust what H2CO3 said, then next part should be to make a generic `queryAllRecords()` and to use SQL parameters instead of string concatenation. Then to have an abstract base class `TableBase` (or similar) to expose `queryAllRecords()` using a table name given by derived classes...and so on...

Comment: @Adriano Yup, this concatenation is an **instant** SQL injection target... :-(

Comment: @H2CO3: There is a free function template `operator+` in `std` in the `<string>` header that takes a `const T*` and a `const basic_string<T>&` as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, most of compiler optimize program by merging equal strings. For example:

```
printf("asdf");
printf("asdf");
```

In this case, maybe program will be compiled as follows. (I use NASM)

```
push str
call _printf
add esp, 4

push str
call _printf
add esp, 4

str: db "asdf", 0
```

If you use `const std::string` constant object, not `const char *`, I think your solution is good.

```
Table getTable()
{
    static const string queryTable1 = "select * from table1";
    return execQuery(queryTable1);
}
```

But note that you shouldn't use `getTable` in global object's constructors if `queryTable1` is global object. As I do, make `queryTable1` `getTable`'s static constant.

Comment: Would you really care about generated assembly code for code that will fetch all records from a database?

Comment: @Adriano In this assembly code, I say about only merging equal strings

Comment: I see but it's unrelated to `const` or not. Moreover IMO a `static const` inside function is pretty useless (unless function is really too long or complicated but then you have other problems). Yes it may be more "clean" but IMO drawbacks of SQL commands in code are much more than this.

Comment: @Adriano const in my code is just saying "This is constant!"... By the way, what is "IMO"? I haven't heard about it; (or I know but I don't know the name)

Comment: I mean: it's a good thing to declare it as `const` but it adds nothing (or almost nothing) to code itself (first or second version in question). Point is IMO (In My Opinion) something else: to have a const **outside** function body (header?) will help you to keep all your SQL commands in one place and all together. If you change a table name then you'll see them. If you change a query...you'll be able to see and change all of them.

Comment: That said it's always a bad idea to hard code SQL (and to concatenate strings to build it). It'll make your maintenance a nightmare, your code ugly, unsafe and hard to read. Such compiler optimization is last of your problems (especially if you have so many hard coded SQL commands that you have to care about size!!!)

Comment: @Adriano the question is about optimizing not SQL, so I answered like these (I think it's bad, too) but As I said last, if string object is global-object, "order of calling global-objects' constructor" problem will coming;;

Comment: I didn't say they have to be global (even worse!). But they should be class members. From generated code point of view `return "a"` or `const static string a = "a"; return a;` are almost same thing. And. Anyway. Who really cares about that?